# How to scrape links from dynamically loaded website (Fincaraiz) using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like help on how to use Scrapy in Python to extract data from the following page

https://fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos/arriendos?ubicacion=cali

I need to **extract the links of each item**, like for example the first shows a detail-link when hovering on the photo:

```
https://fincaraiz.com.co/inmueble/apartamento-en-arriendo/florida-blanca/bogota/6738284
```

[image: 28.578 Apartamentos en Arriendo en Colombia]

#### Problem

This page **loads the content dynamically**, so when I make the request from Scrapy, the result I get is HTML, CSS, JavaScript and some things.

However, the data from the apartments as such is not obtained.

So I cannot apply XPath because the response does not contain the data, instead it is loaded dynamically.

#### Question

How to scrape it without using Selenium, Scrapy Splash , or some other external library ?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer requires the bothersome effort of manually collecting the `Json` for every different url that you're working with. I have found an easier solution which will allow you to upload multiple `start_urls` and arrange the `json` as you wish for the data that you need

I have integrated `scrapy_playwright` rather than `scrapy_splash` because `splash` would return a blank screen and not load for whatever reason - no matter how long I set the timer.

Playwright takes quite a few seconds to load the single page but scrapy is fast as it's asynchronous so you can quickly retrieve all the json from the page.

Here's the script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
from scrapy import http

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/venta/apartamento-en-arriendo/florida-blanca/bogota?pagina=1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'TE': 'trailers',
}
class ListingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listings'
    start_urls = []
    for pages in range(1, 40):
        start_urls.append(f'https://fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/venta/apartamento-en-arriendo/florida-blanca/bogota?pagina={pages+1}')

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback = self.parse,
                meta = dict(
                    playwright = True,
                    playwright_page_coroutines = [
                        PageCoroutine("screenshot", path="image.png", full_page=True), #screenshot to check that you're on the page
                        PageCoroutine("wait_for_timeout", 30000)
                        ]
                )

            )

    def parse(self, response):
    """ Parse the data:
    1. Get the href for each link on the page -
    this provides a unique id used in the json """

        container = response.xpath("//div[@id='listingContainer']/div")
        listing_id = []
        for links in container:
            data=links.xpath(".//a//@href").get()
            try: 
                listing_id.append(data.split("/")[-1])
            except:
                continue

    """Send the Json Request to another parser"""

        for listings in listing_id:
            yield http.JsonRequest(
                url = f'https://fincaraiz.com.co/_next/data/build/es/proyecto-de-vivienda/mirador-del-puerto/puerto-colombia/puerto-colombia/{listings}.json',
                callback = self.parse_listing,
                headers=headers
            )
        
    def parse_listing(self, response):
    """ Parse the Json here however you wish """
        yield {
            'json':response.json()
        }
```

Output:

```
{'json': {'pageProps': {'additional': {'benefit': None, 'deliveryTime': None, 'downPayment': None, 'finishes': None, 'schedule': None, 'financing': None, 'units': None, 'tourUrl': None}, 'capacity': {'name': 'Sin especificar', 'id': 0, 'slug': 'UNDEFINED'}, 'dates': {'renovated': '2022-02-19T20:01:47.783000+00:00', 'deleted': '0001-01-01', 'expired': '2022-05-20T21:16:31.453000+00:00', 'moderated': '2021-10-09T23:25:09+00:00', 'created': '2021-10-09T23:24:31.770000+00:00', 'published': '2022-02-19T21:20:44.207000+00:00', 'updated': '2022-02-19T21:20:44.207000+00:00'}, 'description': 'Espectacular casa Esquinera para uso residencial o comercial, 1 piso:Sala,Comedor,Estudio,Cocina,Deposito,Baño y garaje 2 carros, 2Piso:5 habiraciones y 2 baños, 3Piso: Zona lavadero,lavadoras,1 habiracion y cocina con terraza (El apto del 3 piso esta en obra gris), a 2 cuadras de plaza del quirigua y 20 min portal 80, alimentadores y servicio publico a 1 cuadra, en frente posee parqueadero y zona verde.', ... ...
...
...
...
```

Comment: Could you send the whole project to execute it? or the settings.py file to verify what settings you added

Comment: @Mrx17 I have only included the additional configurations provided on the github for [playwirght](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) whilst setting robot to False. This should get the script up and running for you, if not please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

When you check the [network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) when the site loads, you can find the api call that it uses to dynamically load the contents. You can then replicate the api call simply by copying the curl request and [converting](https://curlconverter.com/) it to python:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.fincaraiz.com.co',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'origin': 'https://fincaraiz.com.co',
    'referer': 'https://fincaraiz.com.co/'
}

json_data = {
    'filter': {
        'offer': {
            'slug': [
                'rent',
            ],
        },
        'property_type': {
            'slug': [
                'apartment',
            ],
        },
        'location_path': 'cali',
    },
    'fields': {
        'exclude': [],
        'facets': [
            'rooms.slug',
            'baths.slug',
            'locations.countries.slug',
            'locations.states.slug',
            'locations.cities.slug',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.slug',
            'locations.groups.slug',
            'locations.groups.subgroups.slug',
            'offer.slug',
            'property_type.slug',
            'categories.slug',
            'stratum.slug',
            'age.slug',
            'media.floor_plans.with_content',
            'media.photos.with_content',
            'media.videos.with_content',
            'products.slug',
            'is_new',
        ],
        'include': [
            'area',
            'baths.id',
            'baths.name',
            'baths.slug',
            'client.client_type',
            'client.company_name',
            'client.first_name',
            'client.fr_client_id',
            'client.last_name',
            'client.logo.full_size',
            'garages.name',
            'is_new',
            'locations.cities.fr_place_id',
            'locations.cities.name',
            'locations.cities.slug',
            'locations.countries.fr_place_id',
            'locations.countries.name',
            'locations.countries.slug',
            'locations.groups.name',
            'locations.groups.slug',
            'locations.groups.subgroups.name',
            'locations.groups.subgroups.slug',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.fr_place_id',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.name',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.slug',
            'locations.states.fr_place_id',
            'locations.states.name',
            'locations.states.slug',
            'locations.location_point',
            'max_area',
            'max_price',
            'media.photos.list.image.full_size',
            'media.photos.list.is_main',
            'media.videos.list.is_main',
            'media.videos.list.video',
            'media.logo.full_size',
            'min_area',
            'min_price',
            'offer.name',
            'price',
            'products.configuration.tag_id',
            'products.configuration.tag_name',
            'products.label',
            'products.name',
            'products.slug',
            'property_id',
            'property_type.name',
            'fr_property_id',
            'fr_parent_property_id',
            'rooms.id',
            'rooms.name',
            'rooms.slug',
            'stratum.name',
            'title',
        ],
        'limit': 25,
        'offset': 0, #set to 25 to get the second page, 50 for the 3rd page etc.
        'ordering': [],
        'platform': 41,
        'with_algorithm': False,
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://api.fincaraiz.com.co/document/api/1.0/listing/search', headers=headers, json=json_data)
data = response.json()
```

For the second url (https://fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos/arriendos/florida-blanca/zona-occidente/bogota?pagina=1):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.fincaraiz.com.co',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'origin': 'https://fincaraiz.com.co',
    'referer': 'https://fincaraiz.com.co/'
}

json_data = {
    'filter': {
        'offer': {
            'slug': [
                'rent',
            ],
        },
        'property_type': {
            'slug': [
                'apartment',
            ],
        },
        'locations': {
            'neighbourhoods': {
                'slug': [
                    'colombia-cundinamarca-bogot\xE1-3632371-florida-blanca',
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    'fields': {
        'exclude': [],
        'facets': [
            'rooms.slug',
            'baths.slug',
            'locations.countries.slug',
            'locations.states.slug',
            'locations.cities.slug',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.slug',
            'locations.groups.slug',
            'locations.groups.subgroups.slug',
            'offer.slug',
            'property_type.slug',
            'categories.slug',
            'stratum.slug',
            'age.slug',
            'media.floor_plans.with_content',
            'media.photos.with_content',
            'media.videos.with_content',
            'products.slug',
            'is_new',
        ],
        'include': [
            'area',
            'baths.id',
            'baths.name',
            'baths.slug',
            'client.client_type',
            'client.company_name',
            'client.first_name',
            'client.fr_client_id',
            'client.last_name',
            'client.logo.full_size',
            'garages.name',
            'is_new',
            'locations.cities.fr_place_id',
            'locations.cities.name',
            'locations.cities.slug',
            'locations.countries.fr_place_id',
            'locations.countries.name',
            'locations.countries.slug',
            'locations.groups.name',
            'locations.groups.slug',
            'locations.groups.subgroups.name',
            'locations.groups.subgroups.slug',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.fr_place_id',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.name',
            'locations.neighbourhoods.slug',
            'locations.states.fr_place_id',
            'locations.states.name',
            'locations.states.slug',
            'locations.location_point',
            'max_area',
            'max_price',
            'media.photos.list.image.full_size',
            'media.photos.list.is_main',
            'media.videos.list.is_main',
            'media.videos.list.video',
            'media.logo.full_size',
            'min_area',
            'min_price',
            'offer.name',
            'price',
            'products.configuration.tag_id',
            'products.configuration.tag_name',
            'products.label',
            'products.name',
            'products.slug',
            'property_id',
            'property_type.name',
            'fr_property_id',
            'fr_parent_property_id',
            'rooms.id',
            'rooms.name',
            'rooms.slug',
            'stratum.name',
            'title',
        ],
        'limit': 25,
        'offset': 0,
        'ordering': [],
        'platform': 41,
        'with_algorithm': True,
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://api.fincaraiz.com.co/document/api/1.0/listing/search', headers=headers, json=json_data)
data = response.json()
```

There are 11 items in `data['hits']['hits']`

Comment: the parameters sent in the post to that api I don't know how they are assembled

Comment: for example https://fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos/arriendos?ubicacion=cali   here the results are 11 but the json returned from the api has more than 11 obviously among those results are the 11 items but they are out of order and I don't know by what criteria the page knows that within all that json it should take only those 11 do you understand me?

Comment: I don't get what you say. `len(data['hits']['hits'])` is `25`, exactly the number of apartments on the first page.

Comment: sorry try with this url https://fincaraiz.com.co/apartamentos/arriendos/florida-blanca/zona-occidente/bogota?pagina=1

Comment: here the results are 11 but the json returned from the api has more than 11

Comment: No, this is an entirely different url, which means that the `json_data` have to be adapted accordingly. Just do as I explained: check the network panel, find the `search` api request --> copy as curl --> convert curl request to python with https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: verifying the network panel I have noticed that the json response of this url brings more data than the page renders, although in this json are the 11 results, there are more, the question is how the page takes from that response json only the 11 data and not the others

Comment: The response has 13 results. Two of those results have an additional `algorithm_rule` key-value pair, for what it's worth.

Comment: What do you mean by algorithm_rule and under what criteria could you select only these 11 and not all 13? since from python I must choose only the 11

Comment: I have added code to retrieve the second url. You'll see that it returns 11 items in `data['hits']['hits']`.

Comment: excellent, thank you, you are a genius! Could you tell me why you changed the "platform" parameter to 41 as I need to know this to apply it to other searches? Do you know what the with_algorithm parameter means? since sometimes it is True or False like the examples you saw
 I also wanted to ask you, the api returns the 11 results out of order, according to the page the first apartment has a fr_property_id=7017348 but the api returns the fr_property_id=6741140 as the first record, do you know how I could order the records so that they remain in the same order of the web interface?